# Mysql Call Details Recodr

Tags: mysql

[this is the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHLEv.png)     Call_id        queue_id        Tm_init        tm_disc
    '780164900',  '24710',        '1422835548',  '1422835559'

I want to queries this 4 columns to get:

"`total calls`, `total talk seconds`, and `average call seconds`, per day and also for specific  month e.g January:

so far I was able to use `select date_format(from_unixtime(Tm_init)` format but I'm not getting the desired result.

e.g outcome

> Date_And_Time 'Feb 02, 2, 2015 12:05 AM, PDT'

but I want to work out the diffs between (Tm_init) and (Tm_disc) in seconds.

[cdr sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHcan.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow..Please give sample input and expected output. Please read .http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Subin; Sample input select date_format(from_unixtime(Tm_disc),'%b %d, %c, %Y %l:%i %p, PDT') AS Date_And_Time
  this is a sample output   ....   'Feb 02, 2, 2015 12:05 AM, PDT'

Comment: You should consider editing the question.By giving table structure,sample data with table,and its corresponding expected output

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667657/sum-not-working-in-mysql-as-desired/

Comment: Im reading the links.... thanks

Comment: Not here please edit question...

Comment: Can you mention the output you need?

Comment: so you need ''Feb 02, 2, 2015 12:05 AM' in seconds right?

Comment: using "unix_timestamp" I want to work out the diffs between (Tm_init) and (Tm_disc) in seconds. Basically  total calls, total talk seconds, and average call seconds

Comment: please provide the entire query in question that u r trying now..

Comment: select date_format(from_unixtime(Tm_disc),'%b %d, %c, %Y %l:%i %p, PDT') AS Date_And_Time

Comment: but it only print.    # Date_And_Time
'Feb 02, 2, 2015 12:05 AM, PDT'

Comment: what is ur expected output then?

Comment: I want to print the total call plus  total talk seconds and average call seconds

Comment: what is theese two columns pecify `Tm_init` and `tm_disc`

Comment: Tm_init – the time at which the call initiated in unix_timestamp.

Comment: Tm_disc – the time at which the call hung up in unix_timestamp

Comment: Can youcheck the answer

Comment: Subin,   Thanks you very much indeed.

Comment: how about if I wanted to second "per day"  and per month

Answer (score 0):

Since

> ```
> Tm_init – the time at which the call initiated in unix_timestamp
>
> Tm_disc – the time at which the call hung up in unix_timestamp
> ```
>
> MySQL `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns a Unix timestamp in seconds since
>   '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init` -  will give  => No of seconds of the call duration.

The query will be

```
SELECT (SUM(`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init`)) AS Total_talk_seconds,
      (AVG(`Tm_disc` - `Tm_init`)) AS Average_seconds_per_cal,
      COUNT(`Callid`) AS Total_No_of_Calls
FROM
dxi_test.`cdr`
```